# How to configure Spring boot login page while securing REST API using OAuth2 social login

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I have a sample web application that uses Spring OAuth2 authentication using Google. The HttpSecurity is configured as follows:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/login", "/oauth/**", "/oauth2/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().permitAll()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("pass")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/list")
            .and()
            .oauth2Login()
            .loginPage("/login")
                .userInfoEndpoint()
                    .userService(oauthUserService)
                .and()
                .successHandler( ... NOT SHOWN ...)
            .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
            ;
    }
```

Now, whenever an unauthenticated request is made, this configuration redirects the browser to the login page. This page shows a link to Google's authentication [Login with Google](/oauth2/authorization/google) as well as a login form.

But I want the browser to be redirected straight to Google's authentication server and not to the application's login page. I don't want any form login/signup feature. I just want the user to login using Google.

What changes need to be made in the above config to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try removing the `formLogin` and the `loginPage` from your configuration..

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/login", "/oauth/**", "/oauth2/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login()
                .userInfoEndpoint()
                    .userService(oauthUserService)
                .and()
                .successHandler( ... NOT SHOWN ...)
            .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
            ;
    }
```

Comment: Oh cool. So, there is no need to set the .loginPage at all!